# Doxygen - <X>:1: warning: return type of member X is not documented

Tags: doxygen

```
/*! \var    GLOBAL_VAR
 *  \brief  This is my global initialisation array for MY_STRUCT
 */
MY_STRUCT GLOBAL_VAR = {
    1,
    3,
    2,
    1,
};
```

I get the following error:

```
<GLOBAL_VAR>:1: warning: return type of member GLOBAL_VAR is not documented
```

But this shouldn't have any return type?!

If I do either of the following the warning goes away:

```
/*! \var    GLOBAL_VAR
 *  \brief  This is my global initialisation array for MY_STRUCT
 *  \returns
 */
MY_STRUCT GLOBAL_VAR = {
    1,
    3,
    2,
    1,
};
```

Or:

```
/*! \var    GLOBAL_VAR
 *  \brief  This is my global initialisation array for MY_STRUCT
 */
MY_STRUCT GLOBAL_VAR = 3;
```

The isn't very useful as it puts a "Returns" into my HTML documentation and the second one breaks my code!

How do I remove this warning?

Thanks

Matt

Comment: what version of doxygen do you have ?

Comment: 1.7.1  I think this is a bug.  I saw it on the message thread on the doxygen website.  Hopefully it'll be fixed in the future

Comment: Should be fixed 1.7.2 and higher. Note that the use of \var is not needed here, you can safely remove this line.

Comment: Thanks, Glad it has been fixed :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://old.nabble.com/%22warning:-return-type-not-documented%22-for-non-functions-td29022040.html

Seems a bug.  Hopefully it'll be fixed in the future.